# Conditional foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, generics, indexing

I have a table named batch with entityId and entityType. `EntityId` can refer to multiple tables based on CHAR enum mentioned in `entityType`.

Is there a way to achieve linkage in MySQL with parent tables with this kind of association.

Comment: Show us your actual `CREATE TABLE` statements, not a description, as well as sample data.

Comment: Are you using `CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY` correctly already elsewhere? And what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: A fk can reference only 1 table. consider a trigger (or a redesign)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have conditional foreign key constraints. However, you can have three separate ones that can work in an exclusive way. For example:

```
create table s (id int primary key not null);
create table m (id int primary key not null);
create table l (id int primary key not null);

create table batch (
  size enum('S', 'M', 'L'),
  s_id int references s (id),
  m_id int references m (id),
  l_id int references l (id),
  check (size = 'S' and s_id is not null and m_id is null and l_id is null
      or size = 'M' and s_id is null and m_id is not null and l_id is null
      or size = 'L' and s_id is null and m_id is null and l_id is not null)
);
```

The check constraint ensures one and only one of them is not null at any given time, and that it must correspond to the value in the `size` column.

**Note**: `CHECK` constraints are only honored starting in MySQL 8.0.17 (or similar version). Before that they were read and *stored* but silently ignored.